# Is it possible to listen to 2 ports when using ssh -L

Tags: ssh

I am using `ssh -L 8080:localhost:8080 me@myLabmachine` to open my web application in my local browser.

I was wondering if there is a way that I could forward 2 ports instead of only 8080 port, namely localhost:3030 and localhost:8080.

Comment: You can easily get te SSH daemon to listen on multiple ports by changing the config file as shown [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/284566/configuration-for-multiple-port-ssh).
You can forward on multiple ports by listing them in the invocation line as shown [here](http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Using_SSH_to_Port_Forward)

Comment: Why not simply start two instances of `ssh`, one listening on each port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ssh -L 8080:localhost:8080 me@myLabmachine
```

You can specify the port-forwarding options `-D`, `-L`, and `-R` more than once on the command line:

```
ssh -L 8080:localhost:8080 -L 3030:localhost:3030 me@myLabmachine
```

If you'd rather put the directives in your ssh config file, you can do that more than once as well:

```
LocalForward 8080 localhost:8080
LocalForward 3030 localhost:3030
```